# Работа с базой данных в django получение данных и запросы

Tags: python, база-данных, django, postgresql

Как получить всю строку из базы данных по ключу?
Я хочу сделать примерно такой запрос:

```
Select * from (Название таблицы) where (название колонки) = (Ключ поиска)
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE "%key%";

Comment: model.objects.filter(field__contains=value).first() ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
ModelName.objects.filter(field=value)
```

Данный запрос вернет все значения из БД, где `field == value`. Вот набор примеров из оф [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: А как я могу получить допустим два значения: where A = %s, B=S?

Comment: @МаркСимпл так тебе ничего не мешает передать два значения в filter, он тогда и будет фильтровать по обоим полям. Есть возможность фильтровать цепочкой